# MongoDB - finding entries using a nested dictionary

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB that I use with python. My entries that looks as follows:

```
{
   a: something
   b: something
   c: {
        d: something
        e: something
        f: something
       }
}
```

I want to query for entries that have a specific values for d and e but I don't care about the value in f.

I tried not specifying f at all (similarly to when I don't care about the b value where I just not adding it to the query):

```
{
   a: a_value
   b: b_value
   c: {
        d: d_value
        e: e_value
       }
}
```

I also tried to use:

```
{
   a: something
   b: something
   c: {
        d: something
        e: something
        f: { $exists : 1 }
       }
}
```

but none of these worked (in fact, I got no results at all)

How my query shall look like?

thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution. The query shall look as follows:

```
{
   a: something
   b: something
   c.d: something
   c.e: something
}
```

I hope it helps someone :-)

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. 
This also explains why we cannot keep  '.' in any mongo key.

Comment: That looks nice. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I.e. automatically build this query.

Answer (score 1):

Extending hashark's answer above. Here is some code to build the query from an object in python.

```py
def obj_to_query(obj, prefix=""):
    "Convert a mongo object into a query."
    query = {}
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            query[prefix + k] = v
        else:
            query.update(obj_to_query(v, prefix=prefix + k + "."))

    return query
```