# Problems with Deleting Elements of Subdictionary in Pymongo MongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a problem for several hours and didnt find an answer yet. My Problem is that i want to delete a key/value pair in subdictionary.

Structure is the following in MongoDB :

```
'_id' : objectId
'title: 'title'
'words': {
       'word1' : [pos0,pos1,pos2,pos3],
       'word2' : [pos0,pos1,pos2,pos3],
        .
        .
        . 
}
```

When I run this query :

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(f"MONGODB_CONNECTION_LINK")
db = client.database
cursor = db['templates'] #OR cursor = db['templates'][index]

query =  { 'words': { f'{word}' : f'{pos}' }}

 x = cursor.delete_many(query)
```

and print out the cursor i get the place back where the deleteResult Object is located. Also when i delete them and print out the return, it says that something was deleted.. But when i go to my database its still there.
Index is the object where i want to delete from. Like Index[0] should be the first Object in the database. But when i try to delete with or without Index its the same result.

BTW also tried some other querys but probably not the right one.

Thanks for help guys

[image: DataStructure in MongoDb]

[[image: Without Index1]

[image: With Index]

Comment: Is there a reason you are using f-strings in your query? Did you try your query on the database side?

Comment: Im using the f-strings because i call the function dynamic and want to delete only some certain values. Im using mongodb atlas, so didnt tried out on the serverside but im sure that its a syntactic issue.. Were able to delete whole 'words' field. Im just wondering what mongodb is deleting. Should give me false back or None according to the docs.

Comment: If you are sure it's a syntactic problem, then I think providing your custom function(s) would help others figure out the error.

Comment: its a problem with the query i guess.. the data i send to the query is correct.. i doublecheck that. The Collection is template. Cursor is at  'templates.0.words')

Comment: thx for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 Problems inside my Code:

1. I didnt access the entries properly according to the Post:

[MongoDB - finding entries using a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138086/mongodb-finding-entries-using-a-nested-dictionary)

2. I saved my Word Values with dots. Therefore i allowed mongodb to store with dots. In this Case its not possible to access the Entries correctly.

Now i just added an new Regex:

regex3 = re.compile(r'[,.]')
re.sub(regex3,'',words.decode_contents()))

I think the Cursor just points to the expected Location of the data. Even if the location exists or not. You dont get back an Error or something like this. Same with the DeleteResult.